How to Implement a Piecewise Function Using SOS2 in GAMS Without Binary Variables in an MILP Model?
I'm working on an MILP model in GAMS, and I need to implement a piecewise function where:
\begin{cases}
0.001 & \text{if } \frac{II(m,n,t)}{II_{\text{max}}} < 1 \\
0.3 & \text{if } \frac{II(m,n,t)}{II_{\text{max}}} \geq 1
\end{cases}
In this problem:
h0(m,n,t) is the output of the piecewise function.
II(m,n,t) is a continuous variable.
IImax is a constant (scalar) used for normalization.
My goal is to avoid using binary variables, or at least minimize them, as my model is already quite complex. I'm considering using SOS2 constraints, but I'm not sure if this is the best approach for this problem. I would appreciate any advice on how to implement this piecewise function either with SOS2 or other approaches that limit the use of binary variables.
Additionally, I welcome suggestions or alternative formulations to handle this kind of piecewise function, whether within GAMS or in a general context.
Thanks in advance for any guidance!
Saeid

Welcome to OR.SE. Would you please, rewrite the PWLF precisely?

@A.Omidi Thanks for reminding that, I have revised the formulation.

This is not a piecewise linear function, as expected by a SOS2 approach. SOS2 assumes that breakpoints are fixed and that there is some interpolation to do. You have a piecewise constant function without a fixed breakpoint.
A binary variable approach with big-M constraints and variable splitting can look like:
$$
\begin{aligned}
&\color{darkred}{\mathit II}_i = \color{darkblue}{\mathit IImax} + \color{darkred}s_i^+ - \color{darkred}s_i^- \\
&\color{darkred}s_i^+ \le \color{darkblue}M\cdot \color{darkred}\delta_i \\
&\color{darkred}s_i^- \le \color{darkblue}M\cdot (1-\color{darkred}\delta_i) \\
&\color{darkred}{h0}_i = 0.001\cdot(1-\color{darkred}\delta_i) + 0.3\cdot\color{darkred}\delta_i \\
&\color{darkred}s_i^+, \color{darkred}s_i^- \ge 0 \\
&\color{darkred}\delta_i \in \{0,1\}
\end{aligned}
$$
(For simplicity, I dropped some indices here.)
The easiest is to use binary variables. Although a SOS2 set is not a binary variable, it requires branching. So, it is discrete in a sense. It does not really save much from a computational point of view. In practice, SOS2 structures are typically more expensive than equivalent formulations using binary variables. (I am contradicting [1] here. MIP solvers have evolved since then and are much better at handling binary variables.).
If you don't have good bounds on $\color{darkred}{\mathit{II}}$, you can use indicator constraints or SOS1 sets instead of the big-M constraints.
[1]. Wilhelm Hummeltenberg, Implementations of special ordered sets in MP software, European Journal of Operational Research, Volume 17, Issue 1,1984, Pages 1-15.

Thanks, that helped a lot.

If your $h0()$ function only takes two possible values (0.001 or 0.3), an SOS2 constraint would be inappropriate. You would need to use a binary variable. In any case, a solver that allows SOS constraints (whether SOS1 or SOS2) is likely to implement them by adding binary variables internally.
Finally, a word of caution. Strict inequalities are not usable in optimization models. You will need to live with one of the following compromises: change $< 1$ in your ratio test to $\le 1$ and accept some ambiguity about $h0$ when the ratio is 1 (to within rounding tolerances); or change it to $< 1 - \epsilon$ for some small positive value of $\epsilon$ and accept an implicit constraint that the ratio cannot fall within $(1 - \epsilon, 1)$ (again to within rounding tolerances).

Dear Professor Rubin
Thank you very much for your comment! Your recommendation was very helpful and made a significant difference in my understanding. I appreciate your input!
